# Linux executable created with PyInstaller not working with subprocess and pexpect

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, subprocess, pexpect

I currently have a python and customtkinter application that works correctly as intended when launched from VSCode, but when I compile it with PyInstaller (using the terminal command: "pyinstaller -F -w -c testGUI.py --collect-all customtkinter") it appears correctly and launches just fine, but none of the commands attached to my buttons execute. I'm thinking it's because I don't have a console for the input and output required for subprocess and pexpect.

Here is my code that uses check_output form subprocess and pexpect:

```
class Application(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
     super().__init__(master)
     self.master = master
     self.pack()
     self.returnDriveList()
     self.createWidgets()

    currentRow = 0
    currentCol = 0                     
    max_cols = 5

    drivesConnected = []
    out = check_output(["lsblk", "--scsi"])
    driveArray = out.splitlines()

    def createWidgets(self):
     frame1 = ctk.CTkFrame(master=None)
     frame1.pack(side="top")
     #self.button1 = ctk.CTkButton(frame1, text="refresh drives", command=lambda: self.refreshDrives())
     #self.button1.pack(side="left")

     self.button2 = ctk.CTkButton(frame1, text="flash all drives", command=lambda: self.flashAllButtonPressed(self.drivesConnected))
     self.button2.pack(side="right")

     frame2 = ctk.CTkFrame(self)
     frame2.pack(side="bottom")
     self.drivesConnected.pop(0)
     self.drivesConnected.pop(0)

     for drive in self.drivesConnected:
        button = ctk.CTkButton(frame2,text=drive,command=lambda s=drive:self.buttonPressed(s))
        button.grid(
        row=self.currentRow,
        column=self.currentCol,
        padx=10,
        pady=10
        )
        self.currentCol += 1
        if self.currentCol == self.max_cols:
            self.currentRow += 1
            self.currentCol = 0

    def flashAllButtonPressed(self, drives):
          for drive in drives:
             for i in range(5):
                print("led flashed")
                child = pexpect.spawn(f'sudo sg_ses --sas-addr=1:0:0:0 --set=ident /dev/{drive}')
                child.expect("password")
                child.sendline("111111")
                print(child.stdin + child.stdout)


    def driveStringToProcess(self, string):
        processedString = string.split()
        return processedString

    def buttonPressed(self, text):
        print(f"for loop button pressed: {text}")
        for i in range(10):
            print("led flashed")
            child = pexpect.spawn(f'sudo sg_ses --sas-addr=1:0:0:0 --set=ident /dev/{text}')
            child.expect("password")
            child.sendline("111111")
        
            #subprocess.run(["sudo", "sg_ses", "--sas-addr=1:0:0:0", "--set=ident", f"/dev/{text}"])
            #subprocess.run(["sleep", ".8"])
            #subprocess.run(["sudo", "sg_ses", "--sas-addr=1:0:0:0", "--set=ident", f"/dev/{text}"])
    
    def returnDriveList(self):
        print("returnedDriveList function called")
        for drive in self.driveArray:
            processedDriveString = self.driveStringToProcess(drive)
            formattedDriveName = str(processedDriveString[0])
            driveName = formattedDriveName.replace("'", "").replace("b", "", 1)
            print(f"Drive name: {driveName}")
            self.drivesConnected.append(driveName)
            print(f"drive appended: '{driveName}'")
    
    def refreshDrives(self):
       print("refresh button pressed")
      
       
ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
root = ctk.CTk()
root.title("Drive Locator")
root.minsize(640, 480)
root.maxsize(1280, 720)

app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

I am aware that my implementation of the password isn't the best practice but this is just a proof of concept for a HDD bay connected to a machine running Ubuntu 20.04.

I am wondering how to get the functions `flashAllButtonPressed()` and `buttonPressed()` working as intended with their implementation of subprocess and pexpect.

Thanks in advance.

I am new to python and tkinter/customtkinter and have read a little bit online about STDIN and STDOUT but not sure how to implement it here.

Comment: Try compiling it without the `-w` option.

Comment: Post a [mre] and debugging details. Is it reproduced when using the ```subprocess``` instead of the ```pexpect```?